# How can a script run privileged commands on a remote system without sudo or ssh passwords?

Tags: debian, sudo

I'm looking to set up my sudoers file correctly, but the documentation I've found doesn't seem to help.

I have a user, e.g. **user1**

I have two Debian servers, **server1** and **server2**.

At present I can connect to either server from my Windows PC using SSH, and when required execute `sudo` to elevate my privileges.

I now have a need to be able to connect from **server1** to **server2** in a shell script, and execute a file on **server2** as `sudo`, without entering the password (either in the script or manually).

I understand I can use the `sudoers` file to allow me to do this.

But how do I do this?

In my `sudoers` file (on **server2** )I have:

```
# User privilege specification
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%user1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I understand I can do something like:

```
%user1 ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/myscript
```

This will then allow **user1** to run the script in */path/to/mysqcript* without entering the password. But, will that prevent me from doing anything else apart from running my script when I connect from my Windows PC.

Ideally I'd want to limit this `NOPASSWD` functionality to connections from **server1**.

Am I missing something here? I'm reluctant to 'test' the changes in case I lock myself out completely.

Comment: Set up key-based ssh authentication first. If you don't password-protect the key, you can *ssh* from server1 to server2 without a password.

Comment: If any of the existing answers solved your problem, please consider accepting it with the checkmark; thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One thing to tweak before getting to the real answer. Using "%user1" means "people in the *group* user1"; you probably just want "user1" to mean user1.

Secondly, sudo has no idea where you are logged in *from* -- only where you are currently running sudo.

Thirdly, ensure you are using "visudo" to make your changes; it will try to prevent you from making syntax errors.

Fourthly, adding a sudoers line only adds to your current access; it will not not prevent you from running other scripts; if you need sudo for those scripts, then you'll need more sudoers entries.

Comment: ok cheers (a rookie error there with the % ). So am I right in thinking then that if I add `user1 ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/myscript ` I will be able to connect as `user1`, and run `/path/to/myscript` without needing to type `sudo` or typing a password? And then I will be able to do everything else the same as before by typing `sudo`?

Comment: I'm confused -- in your question, you're looking to "execute a file on server2 as sudo, without entering the password". Putting the NOPASSWD flag in the sudoers entry accomplishes that. You (or your script) would still need to prefix /path/to/myscript with `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

You asked about restricting the functionality to connections from `server1`.  I would do this with `ssh`.  The code for modifying users is for Debian/Ubuntu.  The principles and most of the other code should be fairly universal.  After making this configuration, to execute the script on `server2` from `server1`, you will issue this command:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/script_identity.pub ruser@server2
```

The above command will connect to `server2` and run your script, requiring no further intervention for `ssh` or `sudo` authentication.  The `ssh` public key file is the only access to run the script remotely on `server2`, thus enabling you to decide which machines and/or accounts can access the script over `ssh`.

The code to accomplish these tasks is exemplified below this description.

This configuration requires a dedicated account on `server2`. There are many good reasons, one of which you've already mentioned, the possibility of locking yourself out of `server2`, or worse, inadvertently modifying the wrong files in your working account.

## Steps to Configure `ssh` for Restricted Remote Access

### On `server1`

1. From the account on `server1` where you'll execute the script, create a new ssh key which will be used only to execute the remote script.
2. Modify the new ssh public key to restrict to execute only one command (see `command=` in the `sshd` manpage).
3. Make a test script that prints the user ids and date.

### On `server2` (all will be done remotely from `server1`)

4. Make a new account on `server2`.
5. Copy the modified public identity file to `.ssh/authorized_keys` in the home directory of the new user on `server2`.
6. Copy the test script to the new users home directory on `server2`.
7. Check all permissions and ownership on all files in the new user's account.

### Code

After saving the following script as `ruser.sh` on `server1`, and, after you understand what it will do, issue this command to execute:

```
$ sh ./ruser.sh ruser server2
```

Save this script as `ruser.sh` in your user account on `system1`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

#
# ruser.sh -- setup user on remote host for secure remote script execution
#
# This is for first time setup!
# Always use a new user on remote host.
#

USAGE="ERROR: Usage: sh $0 remote-username remote-hostname"    
RUSER="${1:?$USAGE}"
RHOST="${2:?$USAGE}"
UNIQUE=$$

# build files that will be transferred to the remote host

# Make the new ssh key, and modify the public key so that
# it can only be used to execute "./rscript.sh"

ssh-keygen -N '' -f ~/.ssh/script_identity
sed -i '1 {
    s,command="./rscript.sh",,
    s,^,command="./rscript.sh" ,
}' ~/.ssh/script_identity.pub

# rscript.sh -- the only script that can be executed
# with the modified public key.

printf '%s' '(id;date) > rscript.out' > /tmp/rscript.sh.$$

# copy the new identity public key and rscript.sh to the remote host

scp ~/.ssh/script_identity.pub "${RHOST}":/tmp/script_identity.pub.${UNIQUE}
scp /tmp/rscript.${UNIQUE} "${RHOST}":/tmp/script_identity.pub.${UNIQUE}

# setup remote user for script execution
# Create new user
# Move identity file and script to new user's home directory.
# Fix ownership and permissions

ssh -t ${RHOST} "sudo /bin/sh -cex '
        adduser --system --shell=/bin/sh ${RUSER};
        mkdir -m0700 ~${RUSER}/.ssh;

        mv /tmp/script_identity.pub.${UNIQUE} ~${RUSER}/.ssh/authorized_keys;
        mv /tmp/rscript.sh.${UNIQUE} ~${RUSER}/rscript.sh

        chmod -R 0600 ~${RUSER}/.ssh/;
        chmod    0700 ~${RUSER}/.ssh/;
        chmod 0700 ~${RUSER}/rscript.sh;
        chown -R ${RUSER}:nogroup ~${RUSER}/;
    '
"

# remove temp files

rm -rf /tmp/rscript.sh.${UNIQUE}
```

Test the above configuration from `server1` by executing:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/script_identity.pub ruser@server2
```

Then check the home directory of `ruser` on `server2` to see that the file `rscript.out` was indeed created, indicating that everything is configured correctly.

If so, modify the `ruser@server2:rscript.sh` to call your `/path/to/myscript`.  Before modifying the sudoers file, issue the ssh command again to run the remote script again to make sure your output and error output are working the way you want.

Now configure `server2`'s sudoers file to allow this new user on `server2` to execute only one script as root without a password.

```
ruser ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/myscript
```

Congratulations, you may now securely run privileged scripts remotely with no `ssh`, `sudo` or system passwords.